# I'm struggling to compare a UIcolor that I have made

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uicolor

I've built a set of custom colours to use in my app, such as lime

```
mylimeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.502 green:1.000 blue:0.000 alpha:1.000];
```

Setting something to this colour works fine, but I'm struggling later in my app when I want to change something depending on which of my custom colours a view has.
I was using the following with no issue:

```
if (bgColor == [UIColor redColor]) {
// do something
}
```

but this breaks as soon as I start to use my own colours.

```
if (bgColor == myredColor) {
// do something
}
```

I can check the background colour in NSLog and it looks exactly as I would expect.

Is there another way for me to find out what the background of something (UIView, UITextFeild, etc) is? I have looked online but only seem to be finding help setting my custom colours, which hasn't been an issue for me.

My next step is going to be to set an integer to a specific number with each colour and check that instead, but it seems that comparing the colour itself would be a better way of doing this.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I feel your code chunks are in wrong places. In the first case [UIColor redColor] and in second code myredColor should be there according to your question.

Comment: You are right, I will edit that to make it more clear when people find this in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UIColor` is a class. Use the `isEqual:` to compare the colors.

Comment: OMG. I can't believe I didn't notice this! I think that just goes to show that it's time for me to get some rest and stop staring at this code. Thank you!!

Comment: By the way: Be careful when comparing colors this way, because they have to be in the same color model to be considered equal. For instance, `#ffffff` does not equal `[UIColor whiteColor]`